# Only show page content if from same server for .load() script

Tags: php, jquery, private-methods

I'm loading HTML content via .load() for tooltips, and have been trying to figure out if there is a way to limit access to the HTML content outside of the script. For example:

```
jQuery("#content_here").load("path/to/content/" + requested_content + ".html");
```

I plan to have 500+ html pages in 'path/to/content' that will be intended for this script. Is it possible to make it unaccessible if you manually navigated to the html page (ie. mysite.com/path/to/content/the_content.html )?

The only thing I can think of would be to make the pages .php instead, and via PHP check if the request is coming from the same server & a .js script before outputting the content. Would this be the best method -- and if so, any examples or pointers in how to check something like that with PHP would be amazing.

Any help would rock. Thanks!

Comment: In php u can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` this will prevent from direct url access.